# Why does a piece of Javascript only work when I have an alert beneath it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following block of code that tracks a click on a button and then records analytics in mixpanel.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.buy').click(function() {
   var myPart = $('#part-name').text();
   var myDistributor = $(this).closest('tr').children('.distributor').text();
   mixpanel.track("Buy Part Link", {"PartName": myPart, "Distributor": myDistributor});
});
</script>
```

On its own, activity is NOT being tracked in MixPanel. However, when I add `alert ('added');` beneath the mixpanel tracking code, all of a sudden it works perfectly.

Why?

Update: since some people asked, the alert was placed beneath the `mixpanel.track` command.

Comment: Where did you add the alert?

Comment: maybe because you are using an `a` tag and the page is refreshing before the script can do it's job

Comment: @musefan Oh, that's a good one. Didn't even think of that.

Comment: try with some callback function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am going to take a guess and say maybe because you are using an `a` tag and the page is refreshing before the script can do it's job.

The solution for that would be to use `event.preventDefault` in your function like so:

```
$('.buy').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //the rest of your code
});
```

By default, an `a` tag will usually navigate to a new page (based on the `href` attribute). If no `href` is set, then it will usually reload the current page. This is a common overlook by most people that are unaware of the `preventDefault` function. But adding this line prevents the link from navigating anywhere.

As @Esailija has said, if all your code within your click function runs synchronously then it would complete fine prior to the page navigation, which suggests that part of it (most like the `.track` call) is running asynchronously - maybe with a timer, or via an ajax call, for example.

Generally, when you find that an alert will fix code, it is likely because something isn't getting enough time to complete. So always look for something that would end the script, this is most likely (and in this case) a page reload/refresh.

If this is not the problem, then we may need to see some of your HTML to help further.

---

Due to your comments, that you still want to navigate, I did a very quick Google search and the documentation tells you how to handle links. [Look at this page](https://mixpanel.com/docs/integration-libraries/javascript#js) and scroll down a bit to the `mixpanel.track_links` function.

Comment: It's not about doing a job but that the job is asynchronous. If it was synchronous, it would complete before navigation.

Comment: @Esailija: Of course, I should have made that part more clear

Comment: +1 for the `alert will fix code`, exactly what I thought after reading the question title  D

Comment: You're right. I was using an `a` tag. But when I implement the code above, it is no longer referring to the link. Is that because of the `preventdefault` function?

Comment: Basically I still want it to click through to that link... but with the code above I can't get it to do that since it seems that is the purpose of `preventDefault`--to prevent that!

Comment: @user1328021: See my edit, mixpanel has a solution for you already